# What's wrong with this try/ except block in Python?

Tags: python, try-except

```
    try:
        user_name = str(input("Enter your full name: "))
    except:
        print("Enter a string")

    user_age = int(input("Enter your age: "))
    user_country = str(input("Enter the country you live in: "))
    user_postcode = str(input("Enter your postcode: "))
```

When I enter an integer for the first one it moves on to the next variable but I want it to say "Enter a string"

Comment: input already returns a string

Comment: Maybe it helps to read as `try <this> and continue except when it screws up with <exception> do this instead`. Since everything is string in the block it never screws up.

Answer (score 0):

*Any* input is already a string.  When you read an integer (such as 123), the input comes as a string (such as "123").  Casting it to **str** does nothing.  You need to be far more specific about what you expect as input, and test for *that*.

For instance, you might want to determine that all characters are in a particular set -- such as letters, spaces, and certain punctuation marks.  Then you'd need to write a particular test or two for those characteristics.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to test if there is a number in the name:
You could do something like this:

```
while True:
    user_name = str(input("Enter your full name: "))
    if [i for i in list(user_name) if i.isdigit()]:
        print("invalid input")
    else:
        break
```

Or maybe better check that all inputs are letters in the alphabet:

```
alphabet = list("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz")

while True:
    errors = 0

    user_name = str(input("Enter your full name: "))
    for i in user_name.split(" "):
        for ii in i:
            if ii not in alphabet:
                errors += 1

    if errors:
        print("You have {} errors".format(errors))
    else:
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

The return type of `input` is always an instance of `str`. Even if the user enters what appears to be a number the result is still a string containing the number. e.g. if they enter `5`, it is still given to you as the string `'5'`.

So instead what you need to do is to check to see if it is an integer.

e.g.

```
user_name = input("Enter your full name: ")
try:
    int(user_name)
except ValueError:
    pass
else:
    print("Enter a string")
```

The above code first reads the input into a variable, this will always be a string. It then tries to convert it to an integer with the `int()` method. If that conversion fails (which is what we want). We just carry on as normal (using `pass`). Otherwise it will hit the `else` and print our your message.

Answer (score 0):

The `except`-part of try-except only run if what's inside the `try`-part throws an error.

An example is divisibility by zero. The following code will throw an error when trying to run it in the python shell;

```
print(5/0)
```

You can catch this error, and print your own message instead of the python shell printing its own. In this case `ZeroDivisionError` is the certain type of error python will throw. With the following code, python will just catch that error, and not any other.

```
try:
     print(5/0)
except ZeroDivisionError:
     print("Cannot divide by zero")
```

If you want to catch all errors, you simply just write `except` instead of `except zeroDivisionError`.

The code inside the `except`-block don't run because there is no error when trying to run what's inside the `try`-block. What is happening inside the try-block is simply assigning an input to a variable. There is no error throwed for this line, and thus the `except`-block don't run.

There are different ways to get the functionality you want. You probably want to repeat that the input needs to be a string, until the user actually enters a string. You can do just that with a `while`-loop. The specific error that is thrown if string to integer conversion fails is `ValueError`.

```
isString = False
while not isString:
      userInput = input("Enter here: ")

      try:
           int(userInput)
      except ValueError:
           # if string to integer fails, the input is a string
           isString = True
      else:
            print("Please enter a string")
```

The while loop above runs as long as `isString` is `False`. First we try to convert from string to integer. If this throws an error, the input is a string, therefore we're setting the isString to `True`, and the while-loop will not run anymore. If the conversion is sucessfull, it implies that the input is actually an integer, and thus the else-statement will run, printing that the user needs to enter a string.